# Check if set is complete by Post's criterion.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following expression: Σ = (M \ (T0 ∩ T1) ∪ (L \ S). I need to check if this set is complete by Post's criterion.

What do I have now?
Let's divide this expression into two smaller ones.
Σ = Σ1 ∪ Σ2.
Σ1 = (M \ (T0 ∩ T1).
Σ2 = (L \ S).
It is obvious that Σ1 ⊆ M and Σ2 ⊆ L.

So we have such a table.

|  | T0 | T1 | L | S | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Σ1 |  |  |  |  | + |
| Σ2 |  |  | + |  |  |

Next, I don't know by which algorithm to check whether the set Σ1 or Σ2 belongs to these 5 special sets. So I am waiting for your solutions to this problem.